# How do we find old answers to questions that are not error related?

Tags: discussion

To all you moderators - we envy you, you seems to have a 6 sense when finding answers!
Just recently I was trying to re-find a list of all Ubuntu's and all the different windows-managers available to us (all the different gui's)  I was trying to convert a couple of friends to our penguin squad!  Alas I was unable to find that lowly long list with all the showy screen-dumps!  Pictures still rate more than a 1000 words !
I have found the proper question and bookmarked it for future reference!
Please how do we ordinary Ubuntu users find all those precious info - when it is not an "How to something or other"

Comment: Search it on Google?

Comment: se's search, google, start typing a question and look at the related questions (which oddly works better than the site search sometimes...)

Answer (score 5):

I searched for "list of window managers ubuntu" in google, this was the top result:

- [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

Comment: Yes thats the one I have bookmarked!  But finding things by using the "Search Q&A" in the top right corner mostly do not find pages like this!!
If we all just used Google (like we all do) all the time, we would not be here!  And these sites would wither and die -- That should not be happening - right!

Comment: Google search engine is much better that the SE one. You can use Google searc for specific sites. Or just type "askubuntu <your question>. Nothing is wrong to search AU using Google.